# How to call a function in a pre-compiled executable file in C++ (calling by command)?

Tags: c++, command

I'm trying to write this program in C++ where I am required to call a function "by the command" from an executable that is pre-compiled. for example. I have compiled my source files giving me the .o files for them. How do I call a function from a .o file that I haven't written or compiled?
I've heard of system but it doesn't seem like I'm using it the right way is I am getting wrong results.

What I am attempting looks something like this:

```
int x, y, a, b, c;
i = system("foo.o foo(y, a, b, c)");
```

Where foo.o should only have the function that should produce the result I want.

Thank you.

Comment: Share a snippet of your code, demonstrating what you've tried.

Comment: On what OS do you want this?

Comment: Generally, .o is not executable but relocatable, so you can link to a .o file when compiling your source file. If you want to use system to run a executable, the target should be an executable. Further more, with system, you cannot call particular function of an executable but just starting with the main(). You can pass in arguments to let the target execute specific function. So you have two ways: link with .o during compilation or use system to call executable. However, it's not clear what you want to do in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your function and other variable and struc and so on in file and compile :

```
g++ yourfile.c
```

Then you have `yourfile.o` , You can build :

```
g++ -o yourmain oject1.o yourfile.o
```

Comment: This doesn't work when I didn't write the .cpp file for foo, or like you are saying , yourfile.c. I only have the .o file which is bulit by foo.cpp file that has a function which returns an integer that I would like to get access to in my main.cpp

Comment: Oh, So you code OOD/P , So you need generate `*.h` for each `class` (just definition) and implement it in `*.cpp` , However no difference, you should build such as above,But i have suggestion: make a `Makefile`  and just use `make command`.

Comment: Also, because of name mangling, you need to be sure that the compilers match.